# Firebase Cloud Function subscribeToTopic timeout

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created the following cloud function using the sample Firebase documentation:

```
export const subscribeToTopic = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const topic = "weeklySurvey";
  const registrationTokens = [
    "c3UXI...ktYZ" // token Truncated here for readability
  ];
  return admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(registrationTokens, topic)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Successfully subscribed to topic:", response);

        //Update: Tried adding next line to avoid timeout error

        return response.status(200).send("Subscribed!");

        //But this returns a predeploy error:
        //Property 'status' does not exist on type 'MessagingTopicManagementResponse'.

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error subscribing to topic:", error);
        return response.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
      });
});
```

The function executes **successfully** with no errors:

```
subscribeToTopic
Successfully subscribed to topic: { successCount: 1, failureCount: 0, errors: [] }
```

**...and then it times out at 60 seconds:**

```
subscribeToTopic
Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
```

Am I missing code that terminates the function after `subscribeToTopic` completes?
Firebase documentation code refers to `MessagingTopicManagementResponse`, perhaps implying that I need more here?

```
admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(registrationTokens, topic)
  .then((response) => {
    // See the MessagingTopicManagementResponse reference documentation
    // for the contents of response.
    console.log('Successfully subscribed to topic:', response);
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not terminating the function by sending back response. Try adding the return response statements as shown below:

```
return admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(registrationTokens, topic)
// ^^ return statement here
  .then((res) => {
    console.log('Successfully subscribed to topic:', response);

    return response.send("Subscribed!")
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.log("Error", e)
    return response.send("Something went wrong")
  })
```

You can read more about this in [Terminate HTTP Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions) section of the documentation.

Comment: I had initially thought the same...so I tried various iterations of res.status() res.send(), res.end() even before posting here.  Returning a status() in the catch block seems to be ok.  But placing any kind of response.status() in the then() block returns the following error on deploy: `Property 'status' does not exist on type 'MessagingTopicManagementResponse'.`

Comment: @Swifter sorry I did not see what your variable names were. It should be `response.send()` instead of `res.send()`. I've renamed it in my answer. Also change the FCM response to `res`.

Comment: Noted. That said, response.status(), response.send(), and response.end() all return `Property ['status'/'send'/'end'] does not exist on type MessagingTopicManagementResponse` predeploy errors.

Comment: @Swifter can you please update your question with the latest function code you have? Do note that there is another var named `response` (returned by subscribeToTopic) . Changed that too

Comment: @Swifter change `.subscribeToTopic(registrationTokens, topic).then((response)` to `.subscribeToTopic(registrationTokens, topic).then((fcmResponse)` otherwise `response` is declared twice.. once at top of functions.

Comment: Updated with suggested code to include `return response.status(200).send("Subscribed!");` in the then() block.  This results in a predeploy error: `Property 'status' does not exist on type 'MessagingTopicManagementResponse'.`. It's possible that I'm not understanding the distinction between more than one `response` here.

Comment: @Swifter can you just copy code from my answer? The return statement? I have different var names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236737/discussion-between-swifter-and-dharmaraj).